# For excepting some character in Range

Tags: regex

I'm wondering how to apply to Regex range with some character.

For example, I want to find  except english character without "o, r, z",

[^orz] can find other language or number character.

Is [a-np-qs-y] only the answer?

Isn't there any answer like [a-Z^orz]? (Of course I know this is wrong.)

Comment: `[a-np-qs-x]` looks good (note that `x` should probably be `y`).

Comment: Ah, mistakes. Thanks. Even though I showed the example, I'm trying to find other solution if there are. The example was simple, but it is hard to set one by one every time. If I have to except "a d e g j l o q s v x z", it will be very ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
(?:(?![orz])[a-z])+
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/NIEvUB/1)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the language, you could also make use of [Character Class Subtraction](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-class-operations.html#subtraction):

For example in Java:

```
[a-y&&[^or]]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ROoRB3/1)